# Problemas al utilizar un método con ID en ListView (OnClick)

Tags: java, android

No consigo utilizar este método:

```
masInformacion((int)info.id);
```

Al utilizar `OnClick` en mi `ListView`

```
    listViewPersonas.setClickable(true);
    listViewPersonas.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
            AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.OnItemClickListener);

            // accion
            masInformacion((int)info.id);

            // toast

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ("Funciona"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
}
```

El error que recibo es al compilar:

```
Error:(197, 71) error: cannot find symbol variable OnItemClickListener
Error:(197, 59) error: illegal start of type
```

Sin embargo, aquí con `onContextItemSelected` si funciona:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo){
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    android.view.MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)menuInfo;
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.opciones_personas, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem item) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_contextual_editar_persona:
            editarPersona((int)info.id);
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_contextual_eliminar_persona:
            eliminarPersona((int)info.id);
            recuperarTodasPersonas();
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_contextual_mas_informacion:
            masInformacion((int)info.id);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected((android.view.MenuItem) item);
    }
}
```

Supongo que el error lo cometo en `AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.OnItemClickListener);` podéis ayudarme? Sé que hay otras preguntas sobre `ListView` y `OnClick` pero mi problema no es sobre eso, es al utilizar este método. Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma de obtener la variable `info` de tipo `AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo` se realiza como lo estas haciendo dentro de 
    `onCreateContextMenu()` :

Si vas a utilizar `info` en otro método, te sugiero crees una variable de ese tipo:

```
private AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info;
```

que definas su valor en `onCreateContextMenu()` :

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo){
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    android.view.MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    //AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)menuInfo;
    info =  (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)menuInfo;
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.opciones_personas, menu);
}
```

y puedes utilizar la variable dentro de `onItemClick()`:

```
 @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
            //AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.OnItemClickListener);

            // accion
            masInformacion((int)info.id);

            // toast

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ("Funciona"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
```

Comment: Tengo un problema raro, a veces funciona pero otras no y recibo el siguiente error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'long android.widget.AdapterView$AdapterContextMenuInfo.id' on a null object reference a que se puede deber? @Jorgesys

Comment: Se debe a que tienes que abrir el menú (onCreateContextMenu() ) para que info se inicialice =| , si no lo abres marcará este error, prueba tu mism@.

Comment: Es cierto lo que comentas, como puedo hacer para no tener que abrir el menú? Ya que quiero un simple clic en el Item @Jorgesys

Comment: Después de definir tu ListView usa registerForContextMenu(listViewPersonas); eso provocará que el ListView trata de abrir el menú.

Comment: Claro, pero eso ya lo estaba utilizando y continua el error, para que me funcione el `OnClick` primero debo abrir el menú contextual @Jorgesys

Comment: Estás libre? Para abrir chat @Jorgesys

Comment: hola @UserNameYo dame 20 mins, llegue a casa pero estoy cleaning the house :/

Answer (score 1):

Tu sola te estas respondiendo. Como bien dices el problema es la linea:

```
AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.OnItemClickListener);
```

Fijate que despues del parentesis no tienes nada mas, es decir, estas haciendo un casteo a algo que no existe, que no hay. Despues de tu **(AdapterView.OnItemClickListener)** tienes que poner algo, al igual que en el otro codigo donde si te funciona.

Espero haberme explicado.

Saludos.